# Haskell Data.HashMap.Strict.InsOrd with ability to retrieve last element

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a data container that allows retrieving data by key and preserves insertion order. I have found that there is Data.HashMap.Strict.InsOrd which fits perfectly, it allows traversing keys in the insertion order, but I do not see a possibility to efficiently retrieve the last inserted element. Is there any way to do that or, maybe, there are other data containers that provide an ability to retrieve last inserted element and elements by key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My [ordered-containers package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ordered-containers-0.2.2/docs/Data-Map-Ordered.html) doesn't offer exactly that operation out of the box. But you can implement it yourself as

```
efficientLastInserted :: OMap k v -> Maybe (k, v)
efficientLastInserted om = elemAt om (size om - 1)
```

and this runs in O(log n) time, n the number of keys in the map.

Your proposed `Data.HashMap.Strict.InsOrd` also appears to offer enough to create this operation:

```
efficientLastInserted :: InsOrdHashMap k v -> Maybe (k, v)
efficientLastInserted = listToMaybe . toRevList
```

My naive reading of the code suggests this is also O(log n) time.